# Using Power MOSFETs to interupt stepper motors

Tags: stepper-motor, powermosfet, stepper-driver

To preface I need to slave one of my steppers on a CNC machine however I have switches that help "square up" the gantry. The problem is this works on two separate drives and using the enable pin on both of them. My solution was to cut power to both steppers (after slaving) using a micro controller and a macro in the machine. The motors are NEMA 34 And operate at 24 or 48 V. I can't remember at the moment. I wanted to use a MOSFET instead of a relay to "kill" power to both coils of the motor but I need help selecting the right size MOSFET. Also given that is an inductive load however operates in pulses should I still include a flyback diode across the drain source? I apologize in advanced it has been a long time since I touched this field of electronics, any additional resources I can read on these applications would be appreciated.

Comment: Most stepper drivers have an enable discrete that when set to the disabled setting cuts power to steppers. You really shouldn't need more relays or mosfets.  Consult your stepper drivers specs on what diodes, capacitors, etc would work well.  The ones for large steppers may even have all they need built in and just need current limits set.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the enable pin which is what’s currently used. Both Y axis motors have their own drive. To team the table it utilizes that function well. My problem is to make room for another axis I have to slave that drive. So it would be one drive to  2 motors. To keep the tram function I’d need to make my own circuit for it

Comment: Mosfets tend to be dependent on the direction of voltage across them; the way around this is to use sets of mosfets like H bridges do... then implement bridges for everything and end up with a big bulky stepper driver. You could use relays to simplify and save on space. Less efficient but no free lunch.

Comment: That was my original plan honestly. Not to concerned about cycle time I was aiming for solid state. I would space the drive to the input of the first drive however the manufacturer of my controller advised against it due to risks. So relays it is I guess. I can double up the current output on the master drive to handle both motors.

Comment: It would still be better to have separate pre-made drivers.  Don't forget that if you break the circuit, you'd at most one relay per coil rather than per wire, and that your acceleration and rate will be affected when you disconnect a motor.

Comment: I’ve entertained slaving a driver to the outputs of the controller. However from the manufacturer it isn’t possible and I have the maximum number of drivers already that the controller can handle.